# Learning ReactJS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS. I'm trying out the code from egghead.io and I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I have loaded babel twice now and have followed along the lesson as described, but it just won't load into the html page. Here is the codes:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>Setup</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "app"></div>
      <script src = "main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App2';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

app2.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    let txt = this.props.txt
    return <h1>{txt}</h1>
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  txt: React.PropTypes.string,
  cat: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
}

App.defaultProps = {
  txt: 'this is the default txt'
}

ReactDOM render(
  <App cat={5}/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "es6-react-setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5"
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you mean `ReactDOM.render`? Are you using ES?

Comment: I did fix that, but still have the same error. And I'm using ES5 & ES6

Comment: Why don't you render in `main.js`? You also don't seem to export anything so I'm not sure what you're importing

Comment: Which file throws that? And if it's main.js can you try renaming it to main.jsx? Could be that your compiler isn't compiling that with ES6 because of it's extension.

Comment: It's just how the lesson is going. I returned it back to what it was before the change.

Comment: @Ben Hare: Tried that. Still getting the unexpected token import error

Comment: If you build it using babel, do you create a main.js file with the final javascript in the same location as the html file? if yes, doesn't it overwrite the original main.js file? 'import' is not a valid keyword in javascript but if your build process is correct, then from babel, you should get a .js file built appropriately to run in the browser. Are you sure you are referencing the correct file in your html?

Comment: what's in your `.babelrc` file ?

Comment: @kilkas: yes, I'm referencing the main.jsx file in the html.

Comment: @PhiNguyen: I can't find a .babelrc file

Answer (score 3):

After installing the Babel presets for ES6 and React you need to enable them either by creating a `.babelrc` file or by opting in in your `package.json` file.

(Confusing) docs here:  http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/

Example `package.json` entry enabling the presets:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
        [
          "env",
          {
            "modules": false
          }
        ],
        "react"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a small example? Cannot understand anything from the doc...

Comment: @RomeoSierra I added an example

Answer (score 0):

`import` is the ES6 syntax. You need to `npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save-dev` to tell babel compile your `ES6` and `React` code.

you can load 2 packages in your `webpack.config.js` file :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I got the following error: '   module.exports = {
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at module.exports '

Comment: Also I already added babel-preset-2015 and babel-preset-react